# Mautic inserir imagem no corpo do Email

Tags: html, css, imagem, email

Essa é a mensagem qeu enviei paar vários sites: ainda nada....

Sou um usuário com pouca experiencia no uso do mautic e já tenho um problemão para resolver atendendo a uma ong que trabalha com doações via boleto bancário.
Eles estão fazendo uma mala direta que também será enviada por email.
Então no corpo do Email tem que inserir a linha digitável do boleto e a imagem do código de barras.
Nos contatos, estou criando dois campos personalizados que serão para colocar os dada linha digitável e o caminho (path) da imagens do código de barras (todos os dois formato texto)
Estou usando o Mautic usando em uma hospedagem que tenho para teste.

Criei o Seguimento, a Campanha, o Email, configurei direitinho os Cron Jobs, testei e está funcionando corretamente.
Coloquei no corpo do email os dois “widigets” para recuperar os dados os dados:

{contactfield=linhadigitavel}
{contactfield=codigodebarras} ‍

No caso do código de barras, coloquei assim no código html do boleto:
<img src="{contactfield=codigodebarras}“>

Lá nos contatos, dentro do campo personalizado “codigodebarras” está o caminho da imagem assim:
http://wbi.alphi.media/mautic/codeimg/6392.jpg (variando conforme o contato, evidentemente)

Deveria estar funcionando direitnho, mas não é o que acontece. A linha digitável está correta, mas no caso da imagem, do caminho, não funciona.

Tentei também desta forma usando uma dica que vi em um site: variável de CSS:

```
:root {
–a1: url(‘{contactfield=codigodebarras}‘);

}

img {

content: var(–a1);

}
```

E no corpo do Email coloco:

```
<img width="200" height="300" />
```

Ou seja, recupero da variável img o caminho que está no campo personalizado {contactfield=codigodebarras}.
Se faço este procedimento diretamente, ou seja, sem usar ‘{contactfield=codigodebarras}, colocando o caminho, funciona direitinho, mas eu quero exatamente que para cada contato seja "impresso" no corpo do Email os dados do boleto que foi gerado para esta pessoa.
Onde estou errando?

Comment: Um membro de um grupo do Mautic lá no facebook, resolveu o meu problema. Abaixo segue o código para quem possa necessitar:

<div style="text-align: center;"><span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="{pro" data-fr-verified="true"><a href="{contactfield=product_url}"><img src="{contactfield=product_image}" alt="{contactfield=product_name}" style="width:207px;height:207px;" class="fr-fic fr-dii" align="middle" width="207" height="207" /></a></span> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Um membro de um grupo do Mautic lá no facebook, resolveu o meu problema. Abaixo segue o código para quem possa necessitar:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="{pro" data-fr-verified="true"><a href="{contactfield=product_url}"><img src="{contactfield=product_image}" alt="{contactfield=product_name}" style="width:207px;height:207px;" class="fr-fic fr-dii" align="middle" width="207" height="207" /></a></span> </div>
```